# Spring boot refresh page on oracle database insert

Tags: oracle, spring-boot

I need a notification (JavaScript alert) to pop up and tell the user to refresh the page whenever a new tuple has been inserted into the ‘messages’ table in my oracle database

Comment: Take a look at the [tour] and then [ask]. Then, edit your question since you'll have the knowledge of how to ask better questions.

Comment: I would like a pony.

Comment: Have a look at Websockets

Comment: Btw Lexi is right. It's clear what you asking for, but your question doesn't show any effort in finding a solution by yourself. What have you already tried?